# Unicode Regex; Invalid XML characters

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre

The list of valid XML characters is well known, as defined by the spec it's:

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

My question is whether or not it's possible to make a PCRE regular expression for this (or its inverse) without actually hard-coding the codepoints, by using Unicode general categories. An inverse might be something like [\p{Cc}\p{Cs}\p{Cn}], except that improperly covers linefeeds and tabs and misses some other invalid characters.

Answer (score 103):

I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but it's helpful to have it here:

Regular Expression to match **valid** XML Characters:

```
[\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]
```

So to remove **invalid** chars from XML, you'd do something like

```
// filters control characters but allows only properly-formed surrogate sequences
private static Regex _invalidXMLChars = new Regex(
    @"(?<![\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFEFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// removes any unusual unicode characters that can't be encoded into XML
/// </summary>
public static string RemoveInvalidXMLChars(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return "";
    return _invalidXMLChars.Replace(text, "");
}
```

I had our resident regex / XML genius, [he of the 4,400+ upvoted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), check this, and he signed off on it.

Comment: Instead of text.IsNullOrEmpty() I think you need string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)

Comment: I would recommend not to strip invalid characters, but rather replace them with the replacement character � (FFFD). Stripping invalid characters makes debugging harder (problems become invisible) and in some cases it can lead to security holes.

Comment: Thank you, this just saved me big time with a huge issue I was having

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Will it help me in this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431354/continue-reading-other-xml-elements-after-exception. Will I not lose some data if I remove those elements from my XML?

Comment: @MattEnright FFFE and FFFF are byte order markers and throw errors if you send the XML stream over to Java.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this in java and it works:

```
private String filterContent(String content) {
    return content.replaceAll("[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]", "");
}
```

Thank you Jeff.

Comment: Elegant one line solution. Thanks Yuval.

Comment: In my case (c#) `\\u000a\\u000d` are valid characters

Answer (score 6):

For systems that internally stores the codepoints in [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16), it is common to use surrogate pairs (xD800-xDFFF) for codepoints above 0xFFFF and in those systems you must verify if you really can use for example \u12345 or must specify that as a surrogate pair. (I just found out that in C# you can use [\u1234 (16 bit) and \U00001234 (32-bit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(VS.71).aspx))

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew7hbz7k(VS.71).aspx) "the W3C recommendation does not allow surrogate characters inside element or attribute names." While searching W3s website I found [C079](http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod/#C079) and [C078](http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod/#C078) that might be of interest.

Comment: While this is a useful implementation tip, it doesn't really answer my question. Let's assume for arguments sake that the implementation has first-rate support of non-BMP characters, so surrogate characters are not needed at all.

Answer (score 4):

The above solutions didn't work for me if the hex code was present in the xml. e.g.

`<element>&#x8;</element>`

The following code would break:

```
string xmlFormat = "<element>{0}</element>";
string invalid = " &#x8;";
string xml = string.Format(xmlFormat, invalid);
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E\x0F\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F]", "");
XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

It returns:

> **XmlException**: '', hexadecimal value 0x08, is an invalid character.
>   Line 1, position 14.

The following is the improved regex and fixed the problem mentioned above:

> &#x([0-8BCEFbcef]|1[0-9A-Fa-f]);|[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E\x0F\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F]

Here is a **unit test** for the first 300 unicode characters and verifies that only invalid characters are removed:

```
[Fact]
        public void validate_that_RemoveInvalidData_only_remove_all_invalid_data()
        {
            string xmlFormat = "<element>{0}</element>";
            string[] allAscii = (Enumerable.Range('\x1', 300).Select(x => ((char)x).ToString()).ToArray());
            string[] allAsciiInHexCode = (Enumerable.Range('\x1', 300).Select(x => "&#x" + (x).ToString("X") + ";").ToArray());
            string[] allAsciiInHexCodeLoweCase = (Enumerable.Range('\x1', 300).Select(x => "&#x" + (x).ToString("x") + ";").ToArray());

            bool hasParserError = false;
            IXmlSanitizer sanitizer = new XmlSanitizer();

            foreach (var test in allAscii.Concat(allAsciiInHexCode).Concat(allAsciiInHexCodeLoweCase))
            {
                bool shouldBeRemoved = false;
                string xml = string.Format(xmlFormat, test);
                try
                {
                    XDocument.Parse(xml);
                    shouldBeRemoved = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (test != "<" && test != "&") //these char are taken care of automatically by my convertor so don't need to test. You might need to add these.
                    {
                        shouldBeRemoved = true;
                    }
                }
                int xmlCurrentLength = xml.Length;
                int xmlLengthAfterSanitize = Regex.Replace(xml, @"&#x([0-8BCEF]|1[0-9A-F]);|[\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F]", "").Length;
                if ((shouldBeRemoved && xmlCurrentLength == xmlLengthAfterSanitize) //it wasn't properly Removed
                    ||(!shouldBeRemoved && xmlCurrentLength != xmlLengthAfterSanitize)) //it was removed but shouldn't have been
                {
                    hasParserError = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(test + xml);
                }
            }
            Assert.Equal(false, hasParserError);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to remove incorrect XML chars in C# with using [XmlConvert.IsXmlChar Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isxmlchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (Available since .NET Framework 4.0)

```
public static string RemoveInvalidXmlChars(string content)
{
   return new string(content.Where(ch => System.Xml.XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray());
}
```

or you may check that all characters are XML-valid.

```
public static bool CheckValidXmlChars(string content)
{
   return content.All(ch => System.Xml.XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch));
}
```

.Net Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/v1TNus

For example, the vertical tab symbol (\v) is not valid for XML, it is valid UTF-8, but not valid XML 1.0, and even many libraries (including libxml2) miss it and silently output invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the regex would look like the following way:

```php
protected function isStringValid($string)
{
    $regex = '/[^\x{9}\x{a}\x{d}\x{20}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+/u';

    return (preg_match($regex, $string, $matches) === 0);
}
```

This would handle all 3 ranges from the [xml specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.0):

```sh
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```