# Write encrypted data to xml

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

In my application I have the following code for the encryption of some data as string:

```
private string EncryptPermission(User user)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    Cryptography cryptography = CreateCryptography(user);
    byte[] val = encoding.GetBytes(user.Permission.ToString());
    byte[] encrypted = cryptography.Encrypt(val);
    string result = encoding.GetString(encrypted);
    return result;
}
```

That works like I want. Now I want to write that data to an xml-file like:

```
internal void WriteUser(User user)
{
    XElement userElement = new XElement("user",
        new XAttribute("id", user.UserId.ToString("N")),
        new XElement("name", user.Username),
        new XElement("password", user.Password),
        new XElement("permission", EncryptPermission(user)));

    XDocument document = GetDocument();
    if (document.Root != null)
    {
        document.Root.Add(userElement);
        SaveDocument(document);
    }
}
```

At the moment I call `SaveDocument` I get an `Exception` like:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x06, is a
>   invalid char.

(Translated from german)

How can I solve this? I've already tried to use `Converter.ToBase64String(..)` and `Converter.FromBase64String(..)` but there I get an exception that the data is too long.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170739/dealing-with-invalid-xml-hexadecimal-characters

Comment: `return Convert.ToBase64String(cryptography.Encrypt(val))` in your encoding method would return a value safe for XML.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Encryption produces bytes, and not all bytes are valid characters, as expected by XML.  Your 0x06 is just one such.  One possible solution is to convert the bytes into Base64 before writing to XML.  Base64 uses only valid characters, at the cost of some increase in size: it uses four characters to write three bytes.

Have a look at the `Convert` class for the C# Base64 conversion methods.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly likely down to a character within the string, has broken the xml.

Add the encrypted string in a CDATA[] tags, within the nodes and you should be fine

[What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Comment: You cannot dump binary data into a cdata section, 0x0 for example is not legal.

Comment: I thought, if its an encrypted string. It would be fine with CDATA. My bad.

Comment: A page on msdn shows, how you could do it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6(v=vs.110).aspx