# Strip escape sequences for invalid XML characters

Tags: java, xml, regex

According to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), only the following charcters are legal:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

I have a string named `foo` containing the JSON representation of an object. Some strings of the JSON object contain escape sequences for characters that are illegal in XML, e.g. `\u0002` and `\u000b`.

I want to strip those escape sequences from `foo` before throwing it to a JSON to XML converter, because the converter is a black box that provides no ability to handle those invalid characters.

Example for what I would like to do:

```
MAGIC_REGEX = "<here's what needs to be found>"  # TODO

String foo = "\\u0002bar b\\u000baz qu\\u000fx"
String clean_foo = foo.replace(MAGIC_REGEX, "�")  # � Unicode replacement character

System.out.println(clean_foo)  # Output is "bar baz qux"
```

How can I achieve that? Bonus points for solutions that use a regex instead of parsing the string and comparing Unicode codepoints.

*I am aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397250/1388240). However, my problem here are the escape sequences of the illegal characters, not the real characters themselves.*

Comment: @Jerry: Of course I could try to write my own hand-crafted regex. The problem is that identifying the illegal characters and illegal multi-byte combinations is already complex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/961504/1388240 So was hoping that someone already ran into the same problem before and solved it.

Comment: Ow, okay. I guess this means I'm not sure (probably since I'm not familiar with the topic of xml and unicode chars) what you're trying to do exactly. Good luck!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the escaping that the XML parser does automatically?

Comment: @his: The parser doesn't really escape. The parser component I am working with seems to parse the JSON, blindly unescape any characters to get a Unicode string, and feed that into an XML library - which obviously crashes because of the illegal characters. That's why I would like to remove the (escaped) illegal characters from the JSON string before feeding it to the parser component. Does this explanation make the problem any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with this regex, which matches almost all illegal characters according to the XML spec, except the ones above `#x10000` (`#x11000` and onwards):

```
# case-sensitive version
\\\\u(00(0[^9ADad]|1[0-9A-Fa-f])|D[8-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[Ff]{3}[EFef])

# case-insensitive version
\\\\u(00(0[^9ad]|1[0-9a-f])|D[8-9a-f][0-9a-f]{2}|fff[ef])
```