# problems reading big XML file with xml2 package and trying to create a working closure

Tags: xml, r, xml2

I am using the `xml2` package to read a huge XML file into memory and the command fails with the following error:

> Error: Char 0x0 out of allowed range [9]

My code looks like the following:

```
library(xml2)
doc <- read_xml('~/Downloads/FBrf.xml')
```

The data can be downloaded at ftp://ftp.flybase.net/releases/FB2015_05/reporting-xml/FBrf.xml.gz (about 140MB) and unpacked it has about 1.8GB.

Has anyone some advise how to figure out which characters are problematic or how to clean the file before reading it.

**EDIT**

Ok, since the file is pretty big I searched for other solutions on stack overflow and try to implement a solution from Martin Morgan which he presented here [Combine values in huge XML-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643580)

So what I have done so far is the following lines of code

```
library(XML)
branchFunction <- function(progress=10) {
    res <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())   # for results
    it <- 0L                            # iterator -- nodes visited
    list(publication=function(elt) {
        ## handle 'publication' nodes 
        if (getNodeSet(elt, "not(/publication/feature/id)"))
            ## early exit -- no feature id
            return(NULL)
        it <<- it + 1L
        if (it %% progress == 0L)
            message(it)
        publication <- getNodeSet(elt, "string(/publication/id/text())") # 'key'
        res[[publication]] <-
            list(miniref=getNodeSet(elt,
                   "normalize-space(/publication/miniref/text())"),
                 features= xpathSApply(elt, "//feature/id/text()", xmlValue))
    }, getres = function() {
        ## retrieve the 'res' environment when done
        res
    }, get=function() {
        ## retrieve 'res' environment as data.frame
        publication <- ls(res)
        miniref <- unlist(eapply(res, "[[", "miniref"), use.names=FALSE)
        feature <- eapply(res, "[[", "features")
        len <- sapply(feature, length)
        data.frame(publication=rep(publication, len),
                   feature=unlist(feature, use.names=FALSE), 
                   miniref=rep(miniref, len))
    })
}

branches <- branchFunction()
xmlEventParse("~/Downloads/jnk.xml", handlers=NULL, branches=branches)
# xmlEventParse("~/Downloads/FBrf.xml", handlers=NULL, branches=branches)
branches$get()
```

I upload the xml file to my server http://download.dejung.net/jnk.xml

The file has only a few kb, but the problem is the result. The second publication entry has an id *FBrf0162243* and a miniref of `Schwartz et al., 2003, Mol. Cell. Biol. 23(19): 6876--6886`.

My results from the code I posted above reports the wrong publication id to the corresponding miniref. The feature ids are correct....

> FBrf0050934 FBgn0003277 Schwartz et al., 2003, Mol. Cell. Biol. 23(19): 6876--6886

Not sure why my code is reporting the wrong values, maybe someone can help me with the closures since this is very new to me.

Comment: maybe try `read_html` as this tries to guess the encoding by itself.

Comment: `dat <- stringi::stri_read_raw("FBrf.xml") ; which(dat == as.raw(0))` shows ~12 null characters.

Comment: @hrbrmstr can I just delete these characters then? And how? @Floo0 I tried `read_html` yesterday but it took more than 20 minutes and I had to quit the process. Will try it again today and see if it is running through. The `read_xml` command quits after a few minutes.

Comment: I tried to use closures now but can not get everything correct...

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally encounter "embedded NULL" error messages that may be similar to this (if the `0x0` in this message means the same `NULL` issue).  My approach is to try to delete them before reading in the file, as I have not found an R package that ignores them.

If you are on Unix or OS X, you could invoke `sed` in your R program via:

```
system( 'sed "s/\\0//g" ~/Downloads/dirty.xml > ~/Downloads/clean.xml' )
```

If this doesn't do the trick, you might want to expand this "blacklist" of characters -- see for example [Unicode Regex; Invalid XML characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397250/unicode-regex-invalid-xml-characters)

If something is still wrong then sometimes I make a character whitelist -- delete everything not in the specified character set..

`sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,"]//g' ~/Downloads/dirty.csv > ~/Downloads/clean.csv`

This is the one I use for .csv data files (don't care about `</etc.>`), so you'd maybe want to expand it to something like `[^[:ascii:]]`:

If you are on Windows, you likely have to go outside of R for this approach -- for example you can use Cygwin instead of the `system()` invocation above.

Answer (score 1):

At the command line, I ran the command `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 FBrf.xml > outfile.xml`
 on your file. It made a difference visible to the eye, but I don't have R installed to test it.

(if on Windows, you would need to install cygwin to get access to iconv)

Comment: iconv is another option, although I have not had as much success with it.  It's worth noting that even in Windows R there is a function for it.  (See `?iconv`)  So a combination of `readLines` and `iconv` could be an option.