# How to check if string is valid xml name

Tags: c#, xml

I want quick function which may be part of my xml parser, I do not want to parse whole string and check if it correct xml.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-common-syn

Comment: @OndrejTucny I know that I can write mine from scratch, but you know - programming is about reusing existing code, not about writing everything from scratch.

Comment: The point is it's not a matter of checking a single character without context. If you are writing an XML parser, then you **must** follow the XML specification.

Comment: Related at the lexical level: [Unicode Regex; Invalid XML characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397250/290085)

Comment: I have removed example code as apparently it was confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really doable without parsing, or at least—in a limited form—without using a regular expression. Names in XML permit different characters as the first character and as second and further characters — see the [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-Name) production.

Should you implement `IsValidXmlChar` without a context, i.e. just checking if the given character is a [NameChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-NameChar), as per the XML specification, the output of your example would be `GridAttributeStuff`.

So you should *at least* tokenize the input text to retrieve valid names, and *parse* the input to retrieve element names, i.e. output `Grid` in your example.

To check if a string is a XML name, the `XmlReader` class offers the [`IsName` static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.isname?view=netcore-3.1). To categorize characters in an XML text, there is the `XmlCharType` struct in [.NET Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlCharType.cs) as well as in [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml/System/Xml/XmlCharType.cs,549849bf89a8f60e), but it's internal.

Comment: Thanks, XmlReader.IsName is what I was looking for!

Comment: OP's question is unclear: The title seems to be asking one thing (allowed chars in tag names), which I believe you addressed (+1), and the code seems to be after another thing (allowed characters anywhere in an XML document), which the duplicate link I've added addresses.

Comment: @Shadow, you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer.

Comment: @kjhughes I've edited question, because as Ondrej pointed out in his answer my code was faulty.

Comment: @Shadow: Ok, but your code still reflects a lexical, not a parse-based, test of character legality, yet your title reflects a parse-based concern.   Anyway, since you accepted this answer, it's clear that it's your title, not your code, that best expresses your problem.  In that case, the duplicate link is less helpful, so I've converted it to a comment.